# How can I connect Pidgin with Facebook chat(XMPP)?

Tags: facebook

I read [this article at Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5469583/how-to-add-facebook-chat-to-your-im-client), and tried it.

But there is a problem, it says that it requires encryption, but it isn't available on this server.

Has anyone here done this before?  What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Incidentally, does anyone know of any way to use XMPP without creating a username? I'd prefer to remain private behind a number.

Comment: Looks like if you want to use XMPP, the answer is no.  http://www.facebook.com/help/?topic=chatclient#!/help/?faq=16747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Facebook instructions](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php)

```
   1.
          * Go to "Accounts" and select "Manage Accounts."
   2.
          * On the Basic tab, enter the following info:
          * Protocol: XMPP
          *
            Username: username
          * Domain: chat.facebook.com
          * Resource: Pidgin
          * Password: 
          * Local alias: Alias
   3.
          * Click the Advanced tab, then enter the following info:
          * Connect port: 5222
          * Connect server: chat.facebook.com
          * (Uncheck the box labeled "Require SSL/TLS")
```

Comment: there is still an error: unable to find alternative xmpp connection methods after failing to connect directly

Comment: username is vague here. facebook email address?

Comment: @Damon, `username` is your facebook username (http://www.facebook.com/help/usernames/general).

Comment: heh thanks i figured that out.. i have been logging in w the email address i signed up with for years and years so I had no concept of what my username was ;P

Comment: @heavyd : How I can do it from another XMPP server *(without a facebook account)*?

Comment: @user2284570 you need a Facebook account to access Facebook Chat

Answer (score 4):

As of [april 30th 2015](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat), facebook shut down their XMPP server (so the above solutions no longer work). Fortunately, this works: https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Facebook Chat](http://code.google.com/p/pidgin-facebookchat/) plugin, which is pretty easy.

Comment: I have been using the FB chat plugin since the early version, and it has been nice, but it still crashes Pidgin every once in a while and does strange things in chats.  A native XMPP implementation is much welcomed!

Comment: @Iain : Yes, but unlike XMPP you have to create a facebook account which mean writing you age; place of birth.. etc :(

Answer (score -1):

I've been using Pidgin to chat on facebook for a while now. I've used it on both Linux and Windows and haven't ever experienced any issues with it. Facebook provides access to their chat server via XMPP. I wrote up about it on my [blog](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/7516/one-liner-chatting-on-facebook-using-pidgin/). Also check out this other [page on howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12527/easily-add-facebook-chat-to-pidgin/) which has more further details.

Here's what my Account details look like:

[image: screenshot of Pidgin Add Account Dialog #1]
[image: screenshot of Pidgin Add Account Dialog #2]

Comment: How I can do it from another XMPP server *(without a facebook account)*?

Comment: [Pidgin has dropped support for Facebook XMPP](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/pidgin-drops-facebook-xmpp).