# Is there a Facebook Chat for Windows Live Messenger?

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-messenger, digsby, facebook-chat

Is there a way to have FaceBook chat in Windows Live Messenger kind of like the way Digsby does it? Like, without making my friends get Windows Live accounts. Is this possible? I have the latest version and I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: For people that visit this question in the feature: Windows Live Messenger will natively support Facebook Chat with their upcoming Social Integration features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**MessengerDiscovery**](http://msgdiscovery.com/) will do this.

It is a nice little free add-on for Live Messenger which lets you chat to your Facebook contacts.

[image]

You can see more screenshots of it in action [**here**](http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=122716&id=68266227376).

Comment: ok, this seemed to work as expected, even though it used a lot of RAM and had so much errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[Windows Live Messenger](http://download.live.com/messenger) only supports Microsoft's proprietary chat protocol.  You can use any chat client that supports the XMPP protocol (ie Digsby, Pidgin, GTalk, iChat) to chat on Facebook, however.  See the [Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php) or [this other post](https://superuser.com/questions/107788/how-can-i-connect-pidgin-with-facebook-chatxmpp) for instructions on how to configure your client.

Answer (score 0):

WLM is only for WLM and Yahoo chat . Facebook is based on XMPP like gChat , iChat, AIM  ... 
I'd recommend using [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) for chatting :) It's simple and it works on many protocols :)