# Reliable facebook XMPP client

Tags: facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

Is there any client out there that could reliably connect to facebook XMPP? I have tried Skype, pidgin, gajim and psi None of them can connect reliably. Some fail silently, others disconnect after 10 seconds or so, other simply crash while trying re-connect.

This leads me to believe that facebooks implementation is somewhat broken. Is there any client that could deal with it?

Comment: Have you seen http://superuser.com/questions/107788/how-can-i-connect-pidgin-with-facebook-chatxmpp yet?

Comment: Yes. It mainly describes a way to set it up in pidgin. But it's not working properly. It connects, shows contacts, etc, but then disconnects after 10 seconds or so. I don't think it's a config problem, as I've tried at least 5 different clients and none of them could connect reliably...

Comment: All of them are reliable. This is a temporary problem on Facebook's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the problem is on Facebook side. [A Twitter search 'confirms' it](https://twitter.com/Nightwolf42/status/267752757493129216).

Answer (score 0):

Their own desktop client seems to work fine (more or less): http://www.facebook.com/about/messenger/?src=sitetour

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a temporary problem on Facebook's end. I have been using Facebook chat through Apple's Messages client for the past few months. It has only begun failing to connect today. As you said it connects for a short period of time before disconnecting again (10 or 20 seconds).